# Multiple options in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class ReservationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = [
            'pk',
            'persons',
            'date',
            'time',
            'table_number',
            'restaurants',
            'menu'
            ]
```

This is my serializer class and I want the menu field to be a multiple checkbox fields
Below is my model class and here menu is a ManyToManyField. But I figured this is not the right way to go.

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    persons = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    table_number = models.IntegerField()
    restaurants = models.ForeignKey('sb_comp.Restraurant', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu = models.ManyToManyField('sb_comp.Menu')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.restaurants
```

Comment: What's the specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example which would kind of put limit on what data should be saved in the Database, suppose if a Technician Department Field does not get a department which exists in the choices field would raise an Exception.

```
   class RepairOrder(models.Model):
        '''create a repair order entry by number'''
        ro_number = models.CharField(max_length=6, help_text='Enter six digit repair order number.')
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        tech = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TECHS, default='none',
       help_text='Technician')
        writer = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=WRITERS, default='none',
        help_text='Service Writer')
        status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUSES, default='unassigned',
        help_text='Work Status')
        promise_time = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='WAIT',
        help_text='Promise Time')
        job_type = models.ManyToManyField(WorkType)
        additional_details = models.TextField(null=True, help_text='Additional Information on Work to be Done')
```

I hope you got the image, Now for it to be Radio Button or Checkboxes, you need to work on your form widgets. Example:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ABC
        widgets = {'type': forms.RadioSelect}

class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    some_field = forms.CharField(choices=MEDIA_CHOICES,
                                 widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    class Meta:
        model = XYZ
```

for More Understanding, you can see this [snippet](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1200/)

Comment: any way to make the choices dynamic instead of being static?

Comment: choices=MEDIA_CHOICES means you need MEDIA_CHOICES list to which you can append dynamically such as MEDIA_CHOICES.append("dynamic_choice")